# What do the following packages do?

Tags: installation, apt

What does each of the packages do? I was installing libmozjs-dev, and it said that the following packages need to be removed:

`couchdb-bin` `desktopcouch` `evolution-couchdb` `gnome-user-guide` `python-desktopcouch` `python-desktopcouch-records` `ubuntu-desktop` `ubuntu-docs` `xulrunner-1.9.1` `yelp`

I see some are self-explanatory, what do the ones with couchdb mean? and if I remove the packages, what effect will it have on my system?

Thanks.

EDIT: I am on Karmic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't say they're explicitly Ubuntu One related.

CouchDB is a database. It's a fairly light, fairly fast way of storing simple data. Applications can use it to store their data. One advantage over things like SQLite (that is faster than CouchDB) is it is much easier to dump a load of records to JSON and import them at another end without conflict. You can do this with relational databases but it usually means layering on some transaction-logging logic which can still cause problems in asynchronous settings. This means it can easily be used in version control systems like Ubuntu One a lot more efficiently.

I think we're getting away from the real point somewhat. The clue that something isn't right should be the presence of `ubuntu-desktop` in that lot. It's just a metapackage but it holds the dependencies for most of the Ubuntu desktop system. If you remove it, and then something does an auto-remove, you'll probably lose most of your desktop.

There's also a conflict with `xulrunner-1.9.1` which is a core dependency of Firefox.

In short, `libmozjs-dev` isn't compatible with whatever you're trying to install it on. I note that `libmozjs-dev` has been dropped from the past two releases so if you're trying to force it into Lucid or Maverick (10.04/10.10) I would stop now and look for another way of installing it (namely downloading it from Mozilla and compiling it yourself).

Comment: yeah, im trying to install libmozjs, to install mongoDB. So i tried making a symbolic link, but still, i see problems.

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo apt-get install mongodb`?

Comment: The .couch files in my system are as binary blobs as the sqlites ones. The main difference is that Desktop is not a relational database but a document oriented one (whatever that means). Replication is easier because it don't use a primary key per table, but a unique uuuid per record. I've been evaluating using it in a project, I run back to sqllite (the project must run on windows too), but it looked interesting.

Comment: Mine was just a simple and quick explanation 'cos I've supposed that he was wondering why that packages were on is pc. Obviously your answer is far away better.

Comment: @Oli I tried that many times, and it needs libmozjs. If I fetch libmozjsdev, then all the above packages are removed. So I made a sym link from firefox's folder, but the mongo shell crashes on basic commands, im guessing because libmozjs is improperly installed. I now built mongo and spidermonkey, its working, but its not convienient. have to go into the folder, and run the shell scripts for the daemon and client separately :((( PS: USing karmic, and updated the OP.

Comment: I dont think CouchDB is light. On my PC, evolution-couchdb is most memory-hogger process (~100 Mb). Probably beacuse of it written on Erlang.

Comment: That sounds more like you have a lot of contacts...  ;-)

Comment: @Kaustubh I don't know what to suggest other than building it yourself and going without the package. In Maverick and Lucid this works without sucking in `libmozjs-dev` so if all else fails and you don't want to built it yourself, perhaps an upgrade might be on the cards.

Answer (score 1):

All the packages that have couch* in their names are related to **Ubuntu One**. `ubuntu-desktop` is a meta-package which install all the standard packages in Ubuntu, you'll find for example also `kubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop`. `gnome-user-guide` is self explanatory, `xulrunner` is related to Firefox, `ubuntu-docs` is the Ubuntu specific documentation, `yelp` is gnome help on line browser.

You can find more detailed description in **Ubuntu Software Center** or in **Synaptic**.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to what others say, `xulrunner` is **not** a dependency of Firefox anymore in recent versions.  It is a dependency of `yelp` (the GNOME help browser) though, and that's probably the reason why several documentation packages get removed too.

CouchDB depends on `xulrunner` too, probably for the JavaScript engine.  CouchDB is used by (parts of) UbuntuOne in the form of DesktopCouch (but other applications can use it too of course).

Also, the last version of Ubuntu that included `libmozjs` was “Karmic”, and I'm pretty sure the functionality it includes is also available in `xulrunner`, so maybe you can use that instead of `libmozjs`?

Comment: I would have trie that, but honestly I spent an entire working day to get mongodb up, and im not willing to sacrifice another. but ill remember it, and try it on a sunday or something. Also, i am using Karmic :P

Comment: In Maverick (and Lucid too, I suppose) MongoDB depends on `xulrunner`.  It might be possible to backport one of those versions to Karmic.